# PHP curl request being sent with no headers

Tags: php, curl, soap

I would really appreciate your help.  I'm not getting anywhere on this issue.

To start here is working code

```
$client = new SoapClient("/var/www/$schema/$space.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
try {
    $result = $client->$service($request);
}
catch (SoapFault $soapFault) {
    //print_r($soapFault);
    echo "ERROR: ". $client->__getLastRequestHeaders ();
    exit();
}
echo "SUCCESS: ". $client->__getLastRequestHeaders ();
exit();
```

I get the appropriate data back from the soap call AND the above code outputs...

```
SUCCESS: POST /server/ws/r/customer HTTP/1.1
Host: soap.server.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 287
```

Now when I try to extend the SoapClient (to add retrying and timeouts)

```
include_once("/var/www/object/soapTest.php");
$client = new SoapTest("/var/www/$schema/$space.wsdl", array('trace' => 1,'timeout' => $timeout_length,'connecttimeout' => $timeout_length));
try {
    $result = $client->$service($request);
}
catch (SoapFault $soapFault) {
    //print_r($soapFault);
    echo "ERROR: ". $client->__getLastRequestHeaders ();
    exit();
}
echo "SUCCESS: ". $client->__getLastRequestHeaders ();
exit();
```

All I get is ERROR: and no other info at all.  So I've tried two 3rd party libraries to extend the SoapClient...both with the same result :

https://github.com/ideaconnect/idct-soap-client/blob/master/src/client.php

https://gist.github.com/RobThree/2490351

My current code is as follows :

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = FALSE)
{
    if (($this->timeout===0) && ($this->connecttimeout===0))
    {
        // Call via parent because we require no timeout
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    }
    else
    {
        // Call via Curl and use the timeout
        $curl = curl_init($location);
        if ($curl === false)
            throw new Exception('Curl initialisation failed');

        $header = array("Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8","User-Agent:PHP-SOAP/5.3.3","SOAPAction:\"".$action."\"");

        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL => false
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
            //CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $this->sslverifypeer
        );
        //print_r($options);
        //exit();

        if ($this->timeout>0) {
            if (defined('CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS')) {    //Timeout in MS supported?
                $options[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS] = $this->timeout;
            } else  { //Round(up) to second precision
                $options[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = ceil($this->timeout/1000);
            }
        }

        if ($this->connecttimeout>0) {
            if (defined('CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS')) { //ConnectTimeout in MS supported?
                $options[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS] = $this->connecttimeout;
            } else { //Round(up) to second precision
                $options[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = ceil($this->connecttimeout/1000);
            }
        }

        if (curl_setopt_array($curl, $options) === false)
            throw new Exception('Failed setting CURL options');

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)){
            throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
        }
        curl_close($curl);
    }

    // Return?
    if (!$one_way)
        return ($response);
}
```

and I also tried pulling the header declaration out of the options array and doing it with

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

after the curl_setopt_array()....no luck.

Any ideas?  I have no idea whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

When you use curl, you do not use parent::__doRequest, so the soapClient can't track your request.

Your code makes an impression that you use curl because you think that SoapClient can't set a request timeout.
That isn't right.

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

> The connection_timeout option defines a timeout in seconds for the
>   connection to the SOAP service. This option does not define a timeout
>   for services with slow responses. To limit the time to wait for calls
>   to finish the default_socket_timeout setting is available.